# BitmapFactory.Options#outWidth returns different size than actual bitmap

Tags: android, android-image, bitmapfactory

I am writing a custom class. There is a bitmap that needs to be calculated for some pre-processing and sizing before it actually gets drawn. The bitmap itself is a pre-processed 9-patch image. In the constructor, there is this code:

```
BitmapFactory.Options bmpOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
bmpOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), BITMAP_ID, bmpOptions);
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), BITMAP_ID);
        
Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "width: " + bmp.getWidth() + " " + bmpOptions.outWidth + "; height: " + bmp.getHeight() + " " + bmpOptions.outHeight);
```

Output on the 7" Samsung Galaxy Tab 7 running Android 3.2.2:

> width: 556 556; height: 890 890

Output on the 10" Motorola Xoom running Android 4.1:

> width: 556 556; height: 890 890

Output on the 7" Nexus 7 running Android 4.2.2:

> width: 740 834; height; 1185 1335

The actual dimensions of the bitmap are:

> mdpi: 558 x 892
>
> hdpi: 836 x 1337

The bitmap is a pre-processed 9-patch which is why the sizes are off by 2 pixels.  I can not understand why the hdpi assets on the Nexus 7 would make this much of a difference.

I have tried these configurations as well:

```
bmpOptions.inScaled = false;
```

and

```
bmpOptions.inTargetDensity = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi;
```

and

```
bmpOptions.inTargetDensity = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi;
bmpOptions.inDensity = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi;
```

and

```
bmpOptions.inTargetDensity = 0;
bmpOptions.inDensity = 0;
```

I have also tried the opposite approach and create a second BitmapFactory.Options for the decoded bitmap and tell it to not scale at all.

All of these provide the same exact results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first 3 lines don't affect the 4th line since the 4th line don't use any of the variables above it. also the "bmpOptions" doesn't get used or filled at all. maybe you've renamed the variables while posting this question?

also, is it possible that the bitmap image file is located on folder that has a density qualifier (or the default one which is like mdpi) ?

only if you put the file into the drawable-nodpi, you will always get the same number of pixels for width&height.

Comment: What I'm doing here was a test. Basically, I'm decoding the same bitmap twice. Once with just the bounds and the other straight. If you set `inJustBounds` to true, in theory (and according to documentation), I should be able to get the size of the resulting bitmap without using time and memory creating it. However, as shown here, this is not the case.  The fact that the two don't effect each other was the point.

Comment: I'll see what happens when I put it in `no-dpi` folder, but I find it odd that `BitmapFactory` isn't scaling one while it's scaling the other. It *should* do both.

Comment: I put the images in nodpi folder and it worked. I find it extremely troubling though that there was this inconsistency when the **whole purpose of `inJustBound` is to give you the dimensions of the image without full decode**.

Comment: well it doesn't do a full decode. it does consider the size that you will get in full decode , so that you could use it without any extra calculations on your side.

Comment: Right, but that's not the case in this. BitmapFactory auto-scales the image when doing a full decode, but doesn't do anything when just trying to get the bounds. In the end, I got different values There's no way of changing this or altering (that I've found), so my only option was to provide tvhdpi assets as well or put the images in nodpi folder.

Comment: I don't understand. when using the no-decoding method you get a different width&height (in pixels) than when using the decoding method ? If so, then i got confused here too. However, i've never done such a thing for a built in image so i could be wrong.

Comment: Yes.  I'm using BitmapFactory to decode the same image resource twice.  Once where I'm just getting the bounds and the other where I'm decoding the entire image as-is.  They give me different dimmensions.  This came about because I'm optimizing now and changing a method structure. The optimization worked on every device except for the Nexus 7.

Comment: Yes after testing out your code i see that you are right. interesting. so in order to get the real number of pixels you should  put the bitmap into the drawable-nodpi folder. i've tried other methods, but they all rely on the fact that you know where you've put the bitmap file. now that i think about it, the only reason why you need to get the real pixels is if you don't wish to use the density mechanism anyway, so why bother...

Comment: OK, i've tried the sample again with 9-patch images, and i see that the values shown in the logs are equal and they are predictable according to the density qualifier. I don't remember what i did last time. However, I've noticed that a google video has talked about getting the correct size of a bitmap. Maybe it could help you : https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=rsQet4nBVi8

Answer (score 5):

To get the actual image size using **inJustDecodeBounds** option, you need to multiply returned **outWidth** and **outHeight** by scale coefficient, which equals to **inTargetDensity/inDensity**.
The sample code is:

```
public static void getBitmapDims(Resources res, int resId, Holder<Integer> width, Holder<Integer> height)
{
    BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    opts.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, opts);

    float scale = (float) opts.inTargetDensity / opts.inDensity;

    width.value = (int) (opts.outWidth * scale + 0.5f);
    height.value = (int) (opts.outHeight * scale + 0.5f);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Could it be the fact that the Nexus 7 screen is ***tv*** dpi and loads the bitmaps from *drawable-**h** dpi*? It is still weird, though, that the *outXXXX* values don't match the final width/height of the bitmap.

Comment: That shouldn't matter.  It's obviously scaling the bitmap somehow, but I explicitly tell it not to and the bitmap is still shrunk.

Likewise, the BitmapFactory.Options should be decoding the bitmap in the same way as the real one.

Comment: Could you change the code in your original example snippet, since it won't compile (e.g your declare bmpOptions but are using maskOptions...), and this way we could take a look at the exact code and figure out what's going wrong. You're right that the behavior looks weird, but it looks like it has something to do with the fact that your code doesn't have a drawable-tvdpi dir (instead, the drawable-hdpi is used) when running on a Nexus 7.

Comment: I put the images in nodpi folder and it worked. I find it extremely troubling though that there was this inconsistency when the **whole purpose of `inJustBound` is to give you the dimensions of the image without full decode**.  By documentation (or at least the implication), setting `inJustBounds` to `true` should act the same way in regards to image dimensions.